# Astropy Coordinates: Second Nearest Neighbour

Tags: python, coordinate-systems, astronomy, astropy

I am using `Astropy.coordinates` to match two astronomical catalogues with RA,DEC coordinates.

I can find the list of nearest neighbours by following the `astropy` documentation[(link to astropy.coordinates documentation)](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/coordinates/matchsep.html) and doing:

```
from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord 
from astropy import units as u
cat1 = SkyCoord(ra=ra1*u.degree, dec=dec1*u.degree)  
cat2 = SkyCoord(ra=ra2*u.degree, dec=dec2*u.degree) 
idx, d2d, d3d = cat1.match_to_catalog_sky(cat2)
```

Where `ra1`, `ra2`, `dec1`, `dec2` are vectors containing the coordinates in the catalogues 1 and 2.

The result `idx` gives, for each object in the catalogue 1, the id of nearest match in the catalogue 2. `d2d` gives the 2d separation between the matches, and `d3d` gives the 3d separation between the matches.

Therefore, to select matches between a desired matching radius, for example, using a 1" radii, I can do:

```
matched=idx[np.argwhere(d2d<1.*u.arcsec)[0]]
```

Now, in order to chose what is the appropriate radii for this last step, I would like to examine what is the distance `d2d` between each source in `cat1`and  their second-nearest-neighbour.

Does anyone knows how can I do this matching process while also recording the second neighbours?

Comment: Could you please provide some dummy data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `match_to_catalog_sky` takes a keyword `nthneighbor` which defaults to 1 (i.e., nearest) but can be set to other values. Changing this should do it.

It seems like you may also want to pay attention to `search_around_sky` method using which you can find all matches up to a separation limit.